# Pegar valores de botões que são gerados randomicamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, button

Eu preciso pegar os valores no evento do click dos botões, que são gerados automaticamente com `php`. Não estou conseguindo fazer a função `javascript/jquery` para fazer isso.

Segue o código que gera eles:

```
while ($i != $max)
{
  $i++;
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","roberto","","manutencao");
  $query = ("select id,nome from aparelhos where id = ".$i." ");
  $aparelho = mysqli_query($con,$query);
  $fetch = mysqli_fetch_row($aparelho);
  $id = $fetch[0];
  $nome = $fetch[1];
  print "<tr>";
  // IDAPARELHO É O ID QUE PRECISO PEGAR A CADA CLICK NO BOTÃO GERADO COM O FOR
  // VOU PRECISAR ENVIAR ESSE ID PARA O PHP FAZER UMA CONSULTA NO BANCO DE DADOS
  //
  print "<td><button id='IdAparelho' value='".$id."' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalVisualizarComponentes' data-index='".$id."' >".$id."</button></td>";
  print "<td><strong>".$nome."</strong></td>";
  print "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Precisa realmente repetir o `mysql_connect`? dentro do `while`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não só não precisa, como normalmente não deveria :) - numa brincadeira dessas a aplicação consome todos os links de conexão disponíveis no servidor.

Comment: Como tens o código no JavaScript?

Comment: Wallace agradeço o seu comentário a respeito de performance e boas práticas, porém no momento essa não é a minha dúvida.

Comment: No momento estou sem nenhum javascript para fazer isso.

Comment: @RobertoAlbino não é questão de performance ou boa prática. Se você quiser, podemos ajudar você no seu problema, mas muito mais do que isso, querendo que as pessoas aprenda a fazer da forma correta, e não só tapar o buraco com uma solução meia-boca.

Comment: Entendi, só não quero perder o foco na pergunta central.

Comment: @RobertoAlbino tente [edit] e colocar mais detalhes além do código, está dificil de entender o problema de fato e o que você quer fazer exatamente. De que valores está falando, como vai usar, etc.

Comment: Editei, para melhor entendimento da situação.

Comment: @RobertoAlbino onde está o JavaScript que tens para pegar o valor dos botões?

Comment: Eu não consegui fazer ele, é desse javascript que estou precisando de ajuda.